# iOS App has Application binary rpath set, and it's considered a vulnerability

Tags: ios, xcode, rpath

I got the following ticket from my company's security testers:

> Description: The binary has Runpath Search Path (@rpath) set. In certain cases an attacker can abuse this feature to run arbitrary executable for code execution and privilege escalation. Remove the compiler option -rpath to remove @rpath. Section "macho"

But this is an issue I never heard of. We are using Carthage for part of our dependencies and others are bundled with the app and used directly.

Current rpath values ar set as follows:

[image]

Comment: Your security testers need to understand how the various platforms work rather than (presumably) simply reporting the results of running some tool. You can't remove the search path, otherwise the dynamic frameworks can't be loaded. You can't inject arbitrary executables into an iOS app; the code bundle is signed by Apple and apps run in a sandboxed environment

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, this was also to my knowledge but I taught I missed something, that's why I opened a question here.